# How to give different values in a select dropdown created by php?

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

I have build a select date dropdown list, containing dates for a period of time, starting from the current day.  I would like to be able to submit the selected date in a database, however I am having problems with creating the option value.

```
<?php
$begin = new  DateTime('today');
$end = new DateTime('today+120day');

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

<select>
    foreach ($period as $dt)
    echo "<option value='[]'>".$dt-> format(" d.m.Y")."</option>"; 

</select>     
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php
 $begin = new  DateTime('today');
 $end = new DateTime('today+120day');

 $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
 $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
?>

<select>
  <?php
   foreach ($period as $dt)
   {
       echo "<option value='". $dt->format("d.m.y"). "'>". $dt->format(" d.m.Y")."</option>"; 
   }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: @CrhiMarie If it works, mark it as the accepted answer, so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can also use this 

<?php
$begin = new  DateTime('today');
$end = new DateTime('today+120day');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

echo "<select>";
    foreach ($period as $dt)
    echo "<option value='[]'>".$dt-> format(" d.m.Y")."</option>"; 

echo  "</select>";     
  ?>
```